# Typescript | Correct way to declare variable types?

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript with Telerik's `Kendo UI`, I am at a bit of an impasse when it comes to how to properly define objects with a type of a widget.

For instance, if I want to declare a `kendoEditor`, I normally do the following...

```
var elements = {
   description: {}
};

elements.description = $('#description').kendoEditor({
   // options
}).data("kendoEditor");

elements.description.refresh(); // this is a function of kendo editor.
```

This works fine in normal javascript, but in typescript I am told that `elements.description` is not a type of `kendo.ui.Editor`. So I try to do it that way ...

var elements = {
   description: kendo.ui.Editor = null
};

elements.description = $('#description').kendoEditor({
    // options
}).data("kendoEditor");

This works fine in the compiler, but at run time it says that it cannot assign it to `null`. But if I do not put `= null`, then it will not compile.

Can anyone express to me the correct way to do this? Additionally, `any` does not seem to be accepted either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type assertion :

```
var elements = { 
    description: {} as kendo.ui.Editor
};
```